# Firebase Cloud Function not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run the following Cloud Function:

```js
exports.getUserData = functions.firestore
  .document('UserData/{id}')
  .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {
    const uid = snap.data.id;
    let uData;
    console.log("onCreate called. uid="+uid);
    await admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
    uData = userRecord.toJSON();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });

    await admin
      .firestore()
      .doc('UserData/${uid}')
      .set({
        userRecord : uData
      });

    return null;
  });
```

It gets deployed allright, as I can see it in the console. But adding/updating a doc in the collection simply does not trigger the function (nothing shows in log).

Comment: It finally showed up in the log, but with an error saying snap.data.id is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things, as I see a few problems

- Seems to me that you want to trigger this function every time there is a new `UserData` collection. If this is the case, you should use the trigger `onCreate`. `onWrite` gets triggered every time a doc is updated, created or deleted.
- You function is creating an infinite loop if you use onWrite. You are updating collections which will triggered the same function, over and over.
- First argument of the function is not a snapDoc, if you are using onWrite. Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)
- This part:

  ```
  await admin
    .firestore()
    .doc('UserData/${uid}')
    .set({
        userRecord : uData
    });
  ```

'UserData/${uid}' is a string not a template string. Use backtick ` not single quote '

- As @renaud-tarnec said, use context.params to get the `id` parameter

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing to the infinite loop. Guess I was too tired to spot it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by doing

```
exports.getUserData = functions.firestore
  .document('UserData/{id}')
  .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {

    const uid = snap.data.id;
    //...
  });
```

you want to assign to the `uid` variable the value of the `{id}` wildcard in the 'UserData/{id}'.

For that you should use the `context` Object, as follows:

```
const uid = context.params.id;
```

and as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) in the doc.